# How to open an URL with different browsers in java with jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I'm currently trying to open an URL in a browser with options of different browsers. example if I give chrome then the URL ("https://www.google.com/") should open in chrome, likewise in firefox.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com")
  .data("query", "Java")
  .userAgent("Mozilla")
  .cookie("auth", "token")
  .timeout(3000)
  .post();
```

The above code does NOT OPEN the browser!

Comment: It is not supposed to open any browser, jsoup is an HTML parser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a browser you need to use selenium, the following example will give you a brief idea about your need. please try to grasp as much as you can from this ex. feel free to comment for any queries.

```
package selenium_Methods;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Bozoinabusride_Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Tushar\\JARs\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://bozoinabusride.blogspot.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement searchThis = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        searchThis.sendKeys("silver");
        driver.findElement(By.className("gsc-search-button")).click();

    }

}
```